# I am getting invalid index error when trying to create an array

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to create an x range and y range, given an initial position, shaped (1,2). I keep getting the error message below. This is when I don't double index into my last_guess.

```
initial = np.array([5., 0.])
def particle_filter(initial, uncertainty, landmarks, n, A, sigma):
    k = float(n)
    print(k/2)
    last_guess = initial
    print(last_guess)
    print(last_guess.shape)
    print(last_guess[1] - k/2)
    weights = np.ones(n)
    weights = weights / k
    mean_and_vars = np.empty((n, 2))

# Create the new particles
    for i in range(1, n):
        new_x_range = np.array([last_guess[0] - k/2, last_guess[0] + 
        k/2])
        new_y_range = np.array([last_guess[1] - k/2, last_guess[1] + 
        k/2])
```

Output:
50.0
[5. 0.]
(2,)
-50.0
/Users/scottdayton/PycharmProjects/Uncertainty Research/particle.py:30: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in true_divide
weights /= n
/Users/scottdayton/PycharmProjects/Uncertainty Research/particle.py:26: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
weights[i] *= likelihood
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/scottdayton/PycharmProjects/Uncertainty Research/particle.py", line 97, in 
particle_filter(init, sigma, obs, n, trans, sigma0)
File "/Users/scottdayton/PycharmProjects/Uncertainty Research/particle.py", line 60, in particle_filter
new_x_range = np.array([last_guess[0] - k/2, last_guess[0] + k/2])
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.

Comment: What is the shape of last_guess? Also, you don't use `i` to create the ranges, so any reason that you have it in a loop?

Comment: Are you possibly modifying `initial` between the `print` and the `for` loop and leaving that part out in the snippet here?

Comment: Reposting of yesterday's question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62648939/i-am-trying-to-create-x-and-y-ranges-using-np-array-but-i-am-getting-the-error.  Without any further information about `last_guess`, which we deduced was the problem variable.  As I pointed out in my answer double indexing of a 1d array will produce this error, `np.array([2])[0][0]`

Comment: initial` is (2,) not (1,2).  Read you own prints!